# Spacemacs: paste into minibuffer

Tags: spacemacs, minibuffer, copy-paste

Is there a way to paste something into the minibuffer?
For example if I want to `eval-expression` and paste something in there neiter `C-v` or (obviously `p`) will work? There has to be a way.

Comment: Have you tried `C-y` (which would be the Emacs standard key) ?

Comment: I thought I had. That works. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>C-y</kbd> does work, but you can also paste into the minibuffer from the default register using `dotspacemacs-emacs-leader-key` instead of `dotspacemacs-leader-key`, in which case you can use: <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can search and paste the contents from any register: for example <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> `phrase you remember`.

Personally, I've just set `dotspacemacs-emacs-leader-key` to an easily accessible key chord and used it everywhere instead of `dotspacemacs-leader-key`.

Comment: I've installed the git layer in spacemacs. When running maggit-clone I'm given a minibuffer asking for the repository URL. `C-y` pastes the `"` buffer for me, but if I try `SPC-r-e-"` in the minibuffer it just says "Whitespace is not allowed here" followed by typing `re"` Any suggestions?

Comment: @bobpaul I gave incorrect keybindings--thanks for the heads up. I've corrected my answer above.